# How do you unnest an int4range to multiple rows in postgres 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, unnest

### Input:

select 'a string', unnest(int4range(98,104));

### Current Output:

"ERROR: function unnest(int4range) does not exist"

### Desired Output:

'a string', 98

'a string', 99

'a string', 100

'a string', 101

'a string', 102

'a string', 103

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`generate_series`:

```
select 'a string', generate_series(lower(r), upper(r))
from (values (int4range(98,104))) r(r);
 ?column? | generate_series 
----------+-----------------
 a string |              98
 a string |              99
 a string |             100
 a string |             101
 a string |             102
 a string |             103
 a string |             104
```